# How to keep track of an upstream when nginx has multiple upstreams?

Tags: nginx, puma

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix: server1
}

upstream app_server_new {
  server unix: server2
}

server {
  location ^~ /about {
    proxy_pass http://app_server_new
  }
  location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app_server
  }
}
```

So when the user hits `/about`, the server redirects to upstream `app_server_new`.

Now I have a `development.log` file for puma. But that doesn't tell to which upstream the redirect went. Is there any way by which I can know if the redirect actually works, like keeping a log about hits to that upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom log for that.
Use the fields of your choice:

```
log_format upstream '$remote_addr - $upstream_addr - $request - $upstream_response_time - $request_time';
```

Then use it in the context specific to your needs:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/upstream.log upstream;
```

More information can be found there:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: this is almost what I need. Thanks. Is there any way by which I can get the name of the upstream called?

Comment: You'll get address and port of upstream in logs. That should be enough.

Comment: I used $proxy_host. It gives the name of the upstream handling the request.